# How to enable create, while also disabling edit for a Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to enable only inserting new records in Kendo grid, but disable editing records?

Best I could do is onDataBound remove "Edit" buttons in JavaScript.
I tried setting `Editable(ed => ed.Enabled(false))` but I get errors during runtime.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
    .Name("Grid" + guid)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "margin:20px" })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Hidden(true);
        //a few more columns

        columns.Command(command =>
            {
                command.Edit().Text(Resources.KendoEdit).UpdateText(Resources.KendoUpdateText).CancelText(Resources.KendoCancelText);
                command.Destroy().Text(Resources.KendoDestroy);
            }).Title(Resources.KendoCommands).Width(180);

    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text(Resources.KendoToolbarCreate))
    .Editable(editable => editable
        //.Enabled(false)
        .Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)
        .DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false)
    )
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Events(events => events.Sync("sync").Error("error"))
        .Model(mod => mod
            .Id(p => p.Id)
        )
        .Model(mod => mod
            .Field(p => p.OldRoleId).Editable(false)
        )

        .Read(read => read.Action("ChangeRole_Read", "ChangeRole"))
        .Create(update => update.Action("ChangeRole_Create", "ChangeRole"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("ChangeRole_Update", "ChangeRole"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("ChangeRole_Destroy", "ChangeRole"))
    )
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable
        .Extra(true)
        .Operators(operators => operators
            .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                .StartsWith(Resources.KendoFilterStartsWith)
                .IsEqualTo(Resources.KendoFilterIsEqualTo)
                .IsNotEqualTo(Resources.KendoFilterIsNotEqualTo)
                .Contains(Resources.KendoFilterContains)
                .DoesNotContain(Resources.KendoFilterDoesNotContain)
                .EndsWith(Resources.KendoFilterEndsWith)
            )
        )
        .Messages(mess => mess
            .Info(Resources.KendoFilterMsgInfo)
            .And(Resources.KendoFilterMsgAnd)
            .Or(Resources.KendoFilterMsgOr)
            .Filter(Resources.KendoFilterMsgFilter)
            .Clear(Resources.KendoFilterMsgClear)
        )
    ) 
    .Scrollable()
    .Pageable(pg => pg
        .Refresh(true)
        .Messages(ms => ms
            .First(Resources.KendoPageableFirst)
            .Last(Resources.KendoPageableLast)
            .Next(Resources.KendoPageableNext)
            .Previous(Resources.KendoPageablePrevious)
            .Empty(Resources.KendoPageableEmpty)
            .Display(Resources.KendoPageableDisplay)
        )
    )
    .Events(ev => ev
        .Edit("edit")
        .Save("save")
        .DataBound("dataBound")
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample for how you are configuring the grid? What errors are you getting?

Comment: What edit mode do you use? There are different approaches based on your setup.

Comment: This is the part that's problematic:
    `.Editable(editable => editable
        .Enabled(false)
        .Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)
        .DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false)
    )`
It disables editing (it's not clickable), but: doesn't remove "Edit" button. I would like to remove the "Edit" button. The best I could do was to remove it with JQ as I said.
More importantly if I leave `.Enabled(false)` than when I try to CREATE new record I get this error: This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request...

Comment: The error is caused by .NET blocking JSON GET requests. You can modify your controller action to accept these by adding a JsonRequestBehavior parameter to the JsonResult returned by your controller action.

Comment: @nukefusion
yeah, but why does setting .Enabled(false) cause this error?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do it would be to set the visibility of the Edit button to None:

```
<style>
    #yourgridid .k-grid-edit
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: The only answer that does the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without the code you are using to initialize the grid, but I'm going to take a shot. If I remember correctly you have to explicitly tell Kendo to add a column with edit/delete buttons like so:

```
.Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(m => m.Whatever);
            columns.Command(command =>
            {
                command.Edit();
                command.Destroy();
            });
        })
```

So if you do have this or something like it in your column definitions, removing it will get rid of the edit/delete but keep the add button in the top bar of the grid.

If this is not how your edit/delete buttons are set up, I'd be happy to revise my answer if you post the grid code.

Comment: Yes this is how i initialize my grid. But, if I remove `command.Edit();` when I click on add new record I get an error about usin GET request. Ok, i put `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in my controller (which I don't want really but if there is no other way it's OK) and there is no more error, but now "SAVE" and "CANCEL" buttons don't exist when adding a new record, there is only "DELETE" button.

Comment: I'm sorry, but unless you post your ENTIRE grid code like we've asked I can't help anymore. I need some way to duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The only work around I have so far is to use popup editing and remove the edit command button from the grid. Now it's just a matter of customising the editor template.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<xxxxViewModel>()
        .Name("xxxx")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {            
            .........

            columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy().Text("Del"); }).Width(80);
        })
        .ToolBar(commands => { 
            commands.Create();
        })
        .Pageable()
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Filterable()       
        .Events(events => {
            //events.Save("xxxx");
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:700px" })          
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Events(events => events.Error("error"))
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.xxxx);
                model.Field(p => p.xxxx).Editable(false);
            })
            .Create(create => create.Action("xxxx", "xxxx"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("xxxx", "xxxx"))            
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("xxxx", "xxxx"))                
        )
)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, saved me more hair pulling. Drawback being you get pop up instead creating inline but I can live with that. Also this "not able to create row inline without edit" seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This fix is in the commented line below:

```
.Columns(cols =>
{

    cols.Bound(c => c.name).Width(300);
    cols.Bound(c => c.dateBuilt);

    cols.Command(cmd =>
    {
        cmd.Select();
        //cmd.Edit();//This is the part to comment out if u want to disable edit
        cmd.Destroy();
    });
})
```

Comment: tnx but: yes this disables Edit, but also disables inserting. Now when I try to insert a new record i don't have Save and Cancel buttons, only Delete button. Also what is `cmd.Select();` this does nothing, just adds a button I don't need that does nothing. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think also like others have suggested you need to remove the

```
command.Edit()
```

from your row and to have a save button, you can add it to the toolbar beside the create using the

```
toolbar.Save()
```

Cheers,
Sameh